# Will Unity run well on my 9400GT?

Tags: unity, 11.04, nvidia

I'd like to ask whether Ubuntu will run better or worse with Unity on my NVidia GeForce 9400 GT.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natty's Unity is build on top of Compiz, so, if *desktop effects* in the Desktop Edition work for you now, then Unity will run too. As long as your graphics card is supported (which your is), it will work very well.

Furthermore, your graphics card is more than fast enough to run Unity very smoothly.